# Mechanism for simultaneous reduction of nitro group (into aniline) and aromatic substitution (into benzonitrile) by Ethyl cyanoacetate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, organic-reduction

I stumbled upon this paper when I'm trying to look at established protocol to synthesize one of the compounds (compound IIk) mentioned in the paper.

[Studies on Aromatic Nitro Compounds. V. A Simple One-Pot Preparation of o-Aminoaroylnitriles from Some Aromatic Nitro Compounds](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/cpb1958/33/4/33_4_1360/_article/-char/en)
[image: Reaction with unknown mechanism]

The paper described transformation of aromatic nitro compounds into o-aminoaroylnitriles by ethyl cyanoacetate in the presence of strong base. While the general scheme showed fused aromatics, this reaction also works for any electron-withdrawing (in addition to the nitro) containing single aromatics.

I have replicate the reaction for compound IIk and I was abled to purified the compound with yield consistent with what was described in the paper.

I have never seen this kind of transformation before, especially with ethyl cyanoacetate. The paper itself mentioned that the mechanism is unknown and I haven't found any subsequent papers that try to elucidate the mechanism.

Anyone has any idea how this reaction works?

Comment: As a noobie, realize that you are expected to show some effort toward an answer. Then answers may ensue.

Comment: That's the problem. None of the typical organic chemistry knowledge applies here.

Reduction of nitrile for example requires a reductant. Obviously ethyl cyanoacetate act as a kind of reductant here, but no known reaction (aside from this) use ethyl cyanoacetate as reductant.
Ethyl cyanoacetate typically is used in the presence of base for aldol-type reaction. But I fail to see how the generated enolate interact with nitro group in the aromatic ring here,

Aromatic substitution too, especially with C-H activation, typically requires metal catalyst. This reaction has none.

Comment: you are correct about ethyl cyanoacetate being a reductant. Note that the initial products contain oxalate units that are formed from the cyano ester.

Comment: This sure is interesting. I wager reaction may still be similar to aldol, with further ring closure and subsequent reopening.

Answer (score 5):

This reaction was conducted using a 3- to 5-fold excess of ethyl cyanoacetate (ECA) and KOH over the arylnitro compounds in dimethylformamide (DMF). It is also important to realize that most KOH is 15% water, which allows for a source of protons in this basic medium. Steps **1** --> **3** (Scheme 1) illustrate a possible route to nitrone **4**. In so doing the ECA moiety is being oxidized as the arylnitro compound is being reduced. Addition of hydroxide to nitrone **4** forms **5**, which can collapse in two ways. One pathway (another will be mentioned later) leads to reactive ethyl oxocyanoacetate **6** and an aryl hydroxylamine. Base deprotonates the hydroxylamine which adds to **6** to afford species **7** and liberates cyanide anion. Addition of cyanide to the aromatic ring of **7** affords arylamine **8** with loss of the half ester of oxalic acid. A second equivalent of **6** reacts with amine **8** to produce target compound **9**.

[image]

Condensation (Scheme 2) of the anion **2** of ECA with ethyl oxocyanoacetate **6** provides ketodiester **10** which condenses with arylamine **8** to form the second targeted product **11**. Scheme 3 provides another mode of collapse of intermediate **5** which leads to **9**. The hydrolysis of **9** and **11** is routine. There are undoubtedly other variants of these Schemes that may apply.

[image]

**Update:** The reference provided by the OP was not the original paper in the series and the picture provided referred to reference 5. The original<sup>[[1]](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/cpb1958/29/5/29_5_1286/_article/-char/en)</sup> reactions with 6-nitroquinoline used KCN as the base providing yields of **9** (IIa) in the 50% range and trace amounts of **11** (IIIa) in reaction times up to 5 hours.  After 24 hours the yield of **9** is greatly reduced with the formation of the oxamic acid derived from ester **9** by an unspecified mechanism of formation. The appearance of 16.5% of **11** should got be construed that **11** is derived from **9**. Significantly, the use of KOH as a base produces **9** in 66.5% yield *without* the formation of **11**.

[image]

1. Y. Tomioka, A. Mochiike, J. Himeno and M. Yamazaki, [*Chem. Pharm. Bull.*, **1981**, *29(5)*, 1286.](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/cpb1958/29/5/29_5_1286/_article/-char/en)

Comment: Interesting and certainly possible. Given the conditions of excess cyanoacetate, why would we not see only the products of cyanide addition to the ring and not cyanoacetate anion addition?

Comment: @Waylander: Good question! There are a lot of questions about this reaction. The yields are moderate. Why isn't structure 10 just deprotonated given its acidity? If the yields of 9 and 11 were high, then every time 6 is generated an arylnitro cmpd is required. But then again, the yields are not quantitative. I'd be interested in your thoughts. Even the authors didn't venture a mechanism. I'm still working on it.

Comment: Why is 6 not hydrolysed immediately in an environment of excess OH-? Its reactivity is similar to ethyl oxalylchloride. Wouldn't 5 be more likely to expel CN-?

Comment: I buy that. The loss of cyanide from 5 is in Scheme 3 which explains the formation of 9 but not 11 unless 9 is saponified to 8. Does not appeal to me. As I noted earlier, there are issues here.

Comment: @Waylander: See the update.